# Parse Error In Pattern for Recursive Mathematical Operators

Tags: haskell

I am a student learning Haskell. My textbook gives the following as an example:

```
(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
m * 0 = 0
m * (n + 1) = m + (m * n)
```

It then asks us to redefine the ^ (positive integral exponentiation) operator in the same manner for an exercise. I assumed the following would work:

```
(^) :: Int -> Int -> Int
m ^ 0 = 1
m ^ (n + 1) = m * (m ^ n)
```

However, it fails to compile, giving a 'parse error in pattern' on the `(n + 1)` bit. Out of curiosity, I tried the multiplication operator as defined in the book's example, and it gave the same error.

Where/how is the textbook wrong, and how do I correct it?

#### Edit

Thank you to those who pointed out that this issue was addressed some years ago. Since the "feature" of n+k pattern matching was removed, how would I modify the textbook example to follow modern good practice?

In short, I now know why the original does not work, but how could it be changed to work?

Comment: This is a deprecated feature of Haskell. To turn it back on, you can always type `:set -XNPlusKPatterns` in GHCi or add `{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just replace `n` with `n-1` on both sides of the equation:

```
(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
m * 0 = 0
m * ((n-1) + 1) = m + (m * (n-1))
```

which is not valid syntax, but of course "simplifies" to the correct version

```
(*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
m * 0 = 0
m * n = m + (m * (n-1))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer not using the NPlusKPatterns extension then you can write:

```
import Prelude hiding ((^))

(^) :: Int -> Int -> Int
m ^ 0 = 1
m ^ n = m * (m ^ (n - 1))
```

The line `import Prelude hiding ((^))` avoids the duplicate definition of (^), since it is already defined in Prelude.